# How can I get rid of Dots from <ul> in <nav>

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

This is what my website looks like in Firefox (notice the dots).

[image: Firefox]

This is how it looks in Chrome (No Dots).

[image: Chrome]

Is there a way that I can get the dots to go away?

Here is my code:

```js
function changeText(button) {
    button.innerHTML = 'Get Started';
}
```

```css
.bcafrees {
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
}

nav.header {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #66C2FF;
}

nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 4%
}

nav ul li {
    width: 4%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0% 1% 2% 2%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 0%;
    padding-top: 0%;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #859999;
}

body {
    background-color: #3A75B0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000000px;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}

body p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size:50px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.getStarted {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    height: 170px;
    width: 300px;
    background: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 60px;
    padding: 20px 10px 50px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.getStarted a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

footer {
    clear: both
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: TW Cen MT;
    padding-top: 5.06%;
    position: relative;
    
}

footer ul {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: TW Cen MT;
}

footer div {
    background-color: #66C2FF;
    height: 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.timmy:hover {
    color: #3A75B0;  
}

.katie:hover {
    color: #3A75B0;
}

.katie {
    display: table;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70px;
}

.timmy {
    display: table;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 95px;
}

footer div ul a{
    width: 100px;
}

hr {
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 70%;
}

.getStartedButton:hover {
    color: #3A75B0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.getStartedButton {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.getStartedButton a:hover {
    color: #3A75B0;
}

.getStarted:hover {
    color: #3A75B0;
}

.getStartedButton.getStarted:hover {
    color: #3A75B0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="welcome.css"/>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Welcome.js"></script>
        <title>BCA Frees</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="bcafrees">
                BCA Frees
            </div>
            <nav class="header">
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li class="home"><a href ="www.bcafrees.com/">Home</a></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li class="about"><a href ="www.bcafrees.com/about">About</a></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li class="faqs"><a href ="www.bcafrees.com/faqs">FAQs</a></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li class="credits"><a href ="www.bcafrees.com/credits">Credits</a></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="p">
                <p>Find Your Friends</p>
                <p>During Your Frees</p>
                <hr />
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="getStartedButton">
                <a href ="/signup">
                    <button onmouseover="changeText(this)" class="getStarted">
                    Get Started
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div id="footer">
                <ul>
                    <li>Copyright BCA Frees 2014</li>
                    <hr class="hr" />
                    <li>Created By:</li>
                    <li class="timmy">Timothy Obiso</li>
                    <li class="katie">Katie Katz</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything--e.g. looking up `li` and `ul` css styling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `list-style: none;` in the `nav ul li` selector:

```
nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 4%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0% 1% 2% 2%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 0%;
    padding-top: 0%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the bullets, or numbers, from a list you can use `list-style: none;`. It's also worth noting that you may want to remove the default `padding` that's automatically created for the list.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
</ul>

<ol>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0; /* Optional to remove default padding */
}
```

An example can be seen on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/): http://jsfiddle.net/jamesjefferyUK/p26afsp1/1/